# Android, reliable exact time background action

Tags: android, background-task

I want continuously execute some actions in background at exact time, until user cancels it.

I have tried AlarmManager and WorkManager, AlarmManager task eventually get cancelled after day or two (maybe when battery gets below some threshold, but that's just a guess). WorkManager tasks are not executed in exact time. Is there any reliable way to execute background tasks in exact time continuously?

Comment: Have you excluded your app from battery saving? You have to do this by hand in the apps setting page shown by Android.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't work in background at all.